# Error when specifying width of column in table

Tags: tables, beamer, width

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c{15mm} | c | c | c | c}
Television & Radio & Washer & Dryer & Computer \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm making a Beamer presentation, and I want to limit the width of some column so that the entry appears as two lines instead of making the column too wide. But when I specify the width as 15mm, I got

```
LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Just use 'p{15mm}' instead of 'c{15mm}'.

Comment: Or, if you want to maintain the centered alignment of the column, load the `array` package and use `m{15mm}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the word "Computer" takes up almost as much space as does the word "Television". Rather than fiddle with one column width at a time in an effort to make the table look OK, I'd use the `tabularx` environment to assure that *all five columns* have the same width.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}  % for 'tabularx' environment
\useapackage{ragged2e} % for \Centering macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| C | C | C | C | C |}
Television & Radio & Washer & Dryer & Computer \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is not specific to `beamer`, so I'll put a general answer first and then a working example using `beamer`.

To wrap text in a table column, here are two simple options:

1. Use `tabular` and specify one of the columns as a paragraph with `p{<width>}`. You must specify the width of that column, while the other columns will fit the width of the contents. The wrapped `p` column will always be left aligned.

   ```
   \begin{tabular}{p{15mm} c c}
   ```
2. Use one of the other table-making packages. The other answer
   demonstrates `tabularx`, which expands the columns to fill a
   specified width for the whole table.

   With `tabulary`, you specify the width of the whole table, and then you can either choose traditional tabular-style columns with lowercase alignment commands `c`, `l`, and `r`; or you can use **uppercase commands** to get a wrapping column. This way you can easily **create a wrapping column with any alignment.**

   ```
   \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{C c c}
   ```

---

Example for `beamer`:

The first frame uses `tabular` and the second, `tabulary`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}

%*******************
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}{p{15mm} | c | c | c | c }
Text that should wrap to multiple lines & Data & Data & Data & Data\\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{frame}
%*******************
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{C | c | c | c | c }
Text that should wrap to multiple lines & Data & Data & Data & Data\\
\end{tabulary}

\end{table}
\end{frame}
%*******************
\end{document}
```